# Anyway to get the trigger to work?

Tags: mysql, trigger, insert

I want to insert last insert query to the another column.For that i wish to use TRIGGERS

```
--
-- Triggers `sync_log`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_sync_id_insertbgnn`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_sync_id_insertbgnn` BEFORE INSERT ON `student_master`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO `sync_log`(`Sync_query`) SELECT * FROM student_master WHERE `SM_NO` = NEW.`SM_NO`;
END
DELIMITER ;
```

This doesn't seems to work.Any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three changes

## CHANGE #1

Add `//` after end

## CHANGE #2

Just insert NEW.`SM_NO` directly into `sync_log`

## CHANGE #3

Make it an AFTER INSERT trigger, to be sure the new `SM_MO` lands in `student_master`

```
--
-- Triggers `sync_log`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_sync_id_insertbgnn`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_sync_id_insertbgnn` AFTER INSERT ON `student_master`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO `sync_log`(`Sync_query`) VALUES (NEW.`SM_NO`);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: What is the different between // and $

Comment: I want to save the newLy inserted query like this `INSERT INTO student_master () VALUES ();`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select a record in student_master which is currently inserted. Because you use before insert it is very likely that the result of your select is empty (assuming that SM_NO is your PK).
Change it to after insert or just use the values from NEW to create a log entry. It isn't very useful to let the server first insert a record and after that reread it.